# Clipboard.GetText() always returns empty string in Mono on Mac

Tags: c#, mono, monomac

Is there a way to get the clipboard on a Mac in Mono that doesn't return an empty string? This is using the latest NON-beta version of mono.

Clipboard.SetText(String) works fine and I can paste to other programs.

```
Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText)
Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text)
Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)
```

All return "" even though Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText) returns true.

EDIT:

The solution ended up being to use NSPasteboard on mac. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being to use NSPasteboard on mac. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I could not ever get Clipboard to return anything. Mono has wrappers around NSPasteboard so it ended up being pretty easy this way.

Comment: I've run into the same problem, could you share the code you use? I can't seem to figure out the NSPasteboard wrappers

Answer (score 0):

It may be that mono is interpreting TextDataFormat.UnicodeText to mean utf-16 but the 'other application' is placing the text on the clipboard as utf-8.

The following is a patch that, if I remember correctly, fixed an issue similar to this.

[clipboard patch](https://bitbucket.org/hindlemail/mono-paratext/src/1ed4282160a0af23dfb92502d2a750e95f7f01d9/patches/bug-306-cannot-paste-copyright-symbol.patch?at=mono-2.10.8.1)

You will need to build mono from and apply the patch to try this out.

Comment: Hmm. I found that patch yesterday but my issue seems to be that even though I have only plain-text (ascii) on my clipboard the Rtf one says I have RTF text on the clipboard which I do not. And all 3 return empty strings regardless. I will try doing a Mac #ifdef that doesn't check Rtf or Plaintext and just looks at Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText) with this patch and post the results back here.