# NSPasteboard and MonoMac

Tags: c#, monomac

I had problems with copy and paste on MonoMac and found [Clipboard.GetText() always returns empty string in Mono on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178864/clipboard-gettext-always-returns-empty-string-in-mono-on-mac) which suggested using `NSPasteboard` but I can't find any good examples or explanation on how to do so in Mono/C#. I think I understand the Objective-C API but the mapping the C# I find confusing so any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example of copying and pasting a string:

```
private static string[] pboardTypes = new string[] { "NSStringPboardType" };

public static void SetText(string text)
{
    NSPasteboard.GeneralPasteboard.DeclareTypes(pboardTypes, null);
    NSPasteboard.GeneralPasteboard.SetStringForType(text, pboardTypes[0]);
}

public static string GetText()
{
    return NSPasteboard.GeneralPasteboard.GetStringForType(pboardTypes[0]);
}
```