# How to get the clipboard text on OSX using DllImport with c#?

Tags: c#, macos, pinvoke, dllimport

the following code sets the clipboard text on OSX. What is the equivalent to read the clipboard text?

```
static class OsxClipboard
{
    public static void SetText(string text)
    {
        var nsString = objc_getClass("NSString");
        var str = objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend(nsString, sel_registerName("alloc")), sel_registerName("initWithUTF8String:"), text);
        var dataType = objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend(nsString, sel_registerName("alloc")), sel_registerName("initWithUTF8String:"), NSPasteboardTypeString);

        var nsPasteboard = objc_getClass("NSPasteboard");
        var generalPasteboard = objc_msgSend(nsPasteboard, sel_registerName("generalPasteboard"));

        objc_msgSend(generalPasteboard, sel_registerName("clearContents"));
        objc_msgSend(generalPasteboard, sel_registerName("setString:forType:"), str, dataType);

        objc_msgSend(str, sel_registerName("release"));
        objc_msgSend(dataType, sel_registerName("release"));
    }

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit")]
    static extern IntPtr objc_getClass(string className);

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit")]
    static extern IntPtr objc_msgSend(IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector);

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit")]
    static extern IntPtr objc_msgSend(IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, string arg1);

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit")]
    static extern IntPtr objc_msgSend(IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, IntPtr arg1, IntPtr arg2);

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit")]
    static extern IntPtr sel_registerName(string selectorName);

    const string NSPasteboardTypeString = "public.utf8-plain-text";
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard/1533566-string

Comment: This question has an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178864/clipboard-gettext-always-returns-empty-string-in-mono-on-mac

Comment: @dj79 can u re-open your answer. it helped me get to an answer so i want to award u the bounty

Comment: @Simon, done. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static string GetText()
{
    var nsString = objc_getClass("NSString");
    var nsPasteboard = objc_getClass("NSPasteboard");

    var nsStringPboardType = objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend(nsString, sel_registerName("alloc")), sel_registerName("initWithUTF8String:"), "NSStringPboardType");
    var generalPasteboard = objc_msgSend(nsPasteboard, sel_registerName("generalPasteboard"));
    var ptr = objc_msgSend(generalPasteboard, sel_registerName("stringForType:"), nsStringPboardType);
    var charArray = objc_msgSend(ptr, sel_registerName("UTF8String"));
    return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(charArray);
}

[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit")]
static extern IntPtr objc_getClass(string className);

[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit")]
static extern IntPtr objc_msgSend(IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector);

[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit")]
static extern IntPtr objc_msgSend(IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, string arg1);

[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit")]
static extern IntPtr objc_msgSend(IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, IntPtr arg1);

[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit")]
static extern IntPtr sel_registerName(string selectorName);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Hans has pointed out, consider using **NSPasteboard**

> Overview
> The pasteboard server is shared by all running apps. It contains data that the user has cut or copied, as well as other data that one application wants to transfer to another. NSPasteboard objects are an application’s sole interface to the server and to all pasteboard operations.
>
> An NSPasteboard object is also used to transfer data between apps and service providers listed in each application’s Services menu. The drag pasteboard is used to transfer data that is being dragged by the user.

You can get more details from this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard

Here is a simple example of copying and pasting a string:

```
private static string[] pboardTypes = new string[] { "NSStringPboardType" };

public static void SetText(string text)
{
    NSPasteboard.GeneralPasteboard.DeclareTypes(pboardTypes, null);
    NSPasteboard.GeneralPasteboard.SetStringForType(text, pboardTypes[0]);
}

public static string GetText()
{
    return NSPasteboard.GeneralPasteboard.GetStringForType(pboardTypes[0]);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: that is not using the dll import approach

Comment: the title of the question explicitly states "using dllImport"

Answer (score -6):

To get data from Clipboard you need to add a reference to Windows.  So do following

1) Project : Add Reference : Net : PresentationCore

2) Project : Add Reference : Net : WindowBase

3) Add to top of module : using System.Windows;

4) Then in code use one of the Clipboard methods like Clipboard.GetText();

Comment: All the ClipBoard method does it calls user32 : https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetClipboardData

Comment: yes. it pinvokes an api that is not available on OSX