# Inserting uris into Gtk.Clipboard with vala

Tags: linux, gtk, uri, clipboard, vala

I am currently trying to implement copy and paste for my application.  The problem is that I can only write plain text or images to the clipboard according to the documentation of [`Gtk.Clipboard`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Clipboard.html): `set_text()`/`set_image()`.

There is also [`set_with_data()`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Clipboard.set_with_data.html), which I think can be used to add a URI or an array of URIs, but I can't figure out; I didn't find any good examples either.

Using the given answer I can fill the clipboard with an array of URIs, but I can read them. When I try, it just calls `get_func()` again and refills it.

```
CTRL C pressed
clipboard get_func called
Received: file:///home/marcel/Downloads/.gitignore

CTRL V pressd
clipboard get_func called
Received: file:///home/marcel/Downloads
Try Pasting: file:///home/marcel/Downloads
```

This is the code I use for testing `CTRL + V`.

```
print ("\nCTRL V pressd\n");
clipboard.request_uris ((clipboard, uris) => {
    foreach ( string content in uris ) {
        print ("Try Pasting: ");
        print (content);
        print ("\n");
    }
});
```

This is the relevant part of `get_func()` for `CTRL + C`.

```
clipboard.set_with_owner (
    clipboard_targets,
    (clipboard, selection_data, info, user_data_or_owner) => {
    print ("clipboard get_func called\n");
    var w = user_data_or_owner as Window;
    File[] files = { w.get_selected_file () };

    switch ( info ) {
        case ClipboardProtocol.TEXT_URI_LIST:
            print ("Received: ");
            string[] uris = {};
            foreach ( var file in files ) {
                print (file.get_uri ());
                print ("\n");
                uris += file.get_uri ();
            }
            selection_data.set_uris (uris);
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the terminal output above, it just refills the clipboard, throwing away its previous values.

Comment: Hi ScriptKiddy. I'm an editor here, and have edited a number of your questions. Your latest ones seem pretty good, but the remaining thing I'd fix is the personal pronoun "I", which you're often writing in lower case. This word is always upper case in English, so if you could write it that way, it will save some editing effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As requested I am providing both an example for writing URIs to clipboard and getting URIs from clipboard. These examples are basically command line programs that get / set the clipboard immediately. In an actual GUI application you would probably react to a button press or, to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> events, use `Gtk.Widget.add_events()` and get / set the clipboard when handling the `Gtk.Widget.event` signal.

## Getting the clipboard

You can request URIs from the X11 clipboard using `Gtk.Clipboard.request_uris ()`. This function takes a callback that will be called once the URIs are available.

Example:

```
public void main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init (ref args);

    Gdk.Display display = Gdk.Display.get_default ();
    Gtk.Clipboard clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get_for_display (display, Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD);

    clipboard.request_uris (recieved_func);
    Gtk.main ();
}

/* Gtk.ClipboardURIRecievedFunc */
private void recieved_func (Gtk.Clipboard clipboard, string[] uris) {
    foreach (var uri in uris) {
        print (uri + "\n");
    }
    Gtk.main_quit ();
}
```

To be compiled with `valac clipget.vala --pkg=gtk+-3.0`

## Setting the clipboard

### Theory:

From the [Qt4 documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qclipboard.html):

> Since there is no standard way to copy and paste files between
>   applications on X11, various MIME types and conventions are currently
>   in use. For instance, Nautilus expects files to be supplied with a
>   x-special/gnome-copied-files MIME type with data beginning with the
>   cut/copy action, a newline character, and the URL of the file.

`Gtk.Clipboard` does not pre-implement setting the clipboard for copying / cutting files. As you said, there is no such `Gtk.Clipboard.set_uris()`.

Instead, you should set the clipboard by providing a callback that X11 gets the clipboard contents from once requested.

These are the steps required:

- Create a bunch of `Gtk.TargetEntry`s that specify what clipboard protocols your app can handle. You'll want to handle the protocols`text/uri-list`, `x-special/gnome-copied-files` and `UTF8_STRING`. Each `TargetEntry` is identified by its `info` field, so that number should be unique (see `enum ClipboardProtocol` in the example below)
- Implement a method of the type `Gtk.ClipboardGetFunc`. This method should fill the `Gtk.SelectionData` object that is passed with the file paths to copy / cut. Check for the `info` parameter to set the SelectionData argument according to the protocol specified.
- Register the callback and the protocols implemented to X11 using `Gtk.Clipboard.set_with_owner` or `Gtk.Clipboard.set_with_data`

### Example:

```
enum ClipboardProtocol {
    TEXT_URI_LIST,
    GNOME_COPIED_FILES,
    UTF8_STRING
}

public void main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init (ref args);

    Gdk.Display display = Gdk.Display.get_default ();
    Gtk.Clipboard clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get_for_display (display, Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD);

    var clipboard_targets = new Gtk.TargetEntry[3];

    Gtk.TargetEntry target_entry = { "text/uri-list", 0, ClipboardProtocol.TEXT_URI_LIST };
    clipboard_targets[0] = target_entry;

    target_entry = { "x-special/gnome-copied-files", 0, ClipboardProtocol.GNOME_COPIED_FILES };
    clipboard_targets[1] = target_entry;

    target_entry = { "UTF8_STRING", 0, ClipboardProtocol.UTF8_STRING };
    clipboard_targets[2] = target_entry;

    var owner = new Object ();

    var rc = clipboard.set_with_owner (
        clipboard_targets,
        get_func,
        clear_func,
        owner
    );
    assert (rc);
    clipboard.store ();

    Gtk.main ();
}

/* Gtk.ClipboardGetFunc */
private void get_func (
    Gtk.Clipboard clipboard,
    Gtk.SelectionData selection_data,
    uint info, 
    void* user_data_or_owner
) {
    print ("GET FUNC!\n");

    File my_file = File.new_for_path ("/home/lukas/tmp/test.txt");
    File my_2nd_file = File.new_for_path ("/home/lukas/tmp/test2.txt");
    File[] files = { my_file, my_2nd_file };

    switch (info) {
        case ClipboardProtocol.TEXT_URI_LIST:
            string[] uris = {};
            foreach (var file in files) {
                uris += file.get_uri ();
            }
            selection_data.set_uris (uris);
            break;

        case ClipboardProtocol.GNOME_COPIED_FILES:
            var prefix = "copy\n"; 
            //var prefix = "cut\n";
            /* use one of the above */

            var builder = new StringBuilder (prefix);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                builder.append (files[i].get_uri ()); 
                /* dont put the newline if this is the last file */
                if (i != files.length - 1)
                    builder.append_c ('\n');
            }
            selection_data.set (
                selection_data.get_target (),
                8,
                builder.data
            );
            break;

        case ClipboardProtocol.UTF8_STRING:
            var builder = new StringBuilder ();
            foreach (var file in files) {
                builder.append (file.get_parse_name ());
            }
            builder.append_c ('\n');
            selection_data.set_text (builder.str, -1);
            break;
        default:
            assert_not_reached ();
    }
    Gtk.main_quit ();
}

/* Gtk.ClipboardClearFunc */
private void clear_func (Gtk.Clipboard clipboard, void* data) {
    ;
}
```

To be compiled with `valac clipset.vala --pkg=gtk+-3.0`

A couple of notes:

- In my example, I could only test `x-special/gnome-copied-files` since I only have Nautilus installed at the moment. I adapted all of the protocols from the Thunar source code (see sources below) but they might still require troubleshooting*
- If you do not want to go through the trouble of implementing this yourself, you could also use the xclip command line tool: https://askubuntu.com/a/210428/345569 However, IMHO implementing this yourself is a little more elegant.

## Sources:

- Article from the Ubuntu Forums: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2135919.html
- Thunar source code (especially thunar/thunar/thunar-clipboard-manager.c): https://github.com/xfce-mirror/thunar/blob/3de231d2dec33ca48b73391386d442231baace3e/thunar/thunar-clipboard-manager.c
- Qt4 documentation: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qclipboard.html

Comment: Well, i can now fill the clipboard, but don't know how to read. Ofc this still asnwers my initial question :D But whenever i try to get the content it just fills it again. I might have mistunderstood the whole thing a bit?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean by "it just fills it again". You can generally read URI's from clipboard using Gtk.Clipboard.request_uris ()

Comment: Added an example for Gtk.Clipboard.request_uris()

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @stunningpotato Thank you!!! Moreover thanks a lot for having answered ath this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215967/gtk-ckipboard-pasting-files-from-a-source-with-custom-uri-scheme?noredirect=1#comment87848694_36215967

Comment: Interestingly enough, Python introspection bindings also don't have `Gtk.Clipboard.set_uris()` and the avalable `.set_data()` function results in `RuntimeError: Data access methods are unsupported. Use normal Python attributes instead`  , so I guess I'll have to resort to Vala and this solution, potentially. Either way, +1 for comprehensive answer with example